# Return all objects relationships recursive

Tags: django

How i can return all relationships on recursive table  on django
Structure(model):

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=estado_choices,)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='category', db_index=False)
```

I would like return like this on template:

```
_______________________________________________
#  |Category        |name          |description|
________________________________________________
1  | Principal      |Example       |example 3  |
2  | Subprincipal   |subprincipal  |example 3  |
3  | Subprincipal 2 |subprincipal 2| example3
```

i dont know how return this relationship.. please someone idea..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather that implementing a hierarchical category model of your own. Build on what others have done! There is a library called `django-mptt` that works very well for this. The [documentation](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) will tell you all you need to know about getting a recursive results from your categories.